# Show that $M_k(G)$ is the set of independent sets of a matroid!

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees, matroids

Let $G = (V,E)$ be an undirected graph. Set $M_k(G) = (E,S)$ where 
$$S = \{F ∪M | F ⊆ E,(V,F) \;\text{acyclic},M ⊆ E,|M| ≤ k\}.$$

Show that $M_k(G)$ is the set of independent sets of a matroid! In particular, the set of spanning forests of an undirected graph $G = (V,E)$ is the set of independent sets of a matroid.

I really need help with this one, I have no idea where to start.

Comment: I am confused.  $M_k(G)$ is not a set, but an ordered pair of sets.  What do you mean by "$M_k(G)$ is the set of independent sets of a matroid"?  And are you talking about finite matroids (so $V$ and $E$ are finite sets)?  It is kinda difficult to deal with infinite matroids.

Comment: Are you instead saying that $M_k(G)=(E,S)$ is a matroid on the ground set $E$ with $S$ being the family of independent sets?

Comment: This is word for word from the task description... idk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the OP means to say that $M_k(G)=(E,S)$ is a matroid on the ground set $E$ with $S$ being the family of independent sets.  I assume here that $G$ is a finite graph (so $V$ and $E$ are finite sets).  I don't know how to deal with infinite matroids.  The second part of the task is simply showing that $M_0(G)$ is a matroid, which is implied by the first part.

From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid), there are three checkpoints. For the first one, it is easy to see that $\emptyset \in S$, since $F=\emptyset$ and $M=\emptyset$ gives $\emptyset=F\cup M\in S$.

For the hereditary property, let $F\cup M\in S$ and $T\subseteq F\cup M$.  Write $T_F=T\cap F$ and $T_M=T\cap M$.  Then, the edge induced subgraph $G[T_F]$ of $G$ is a forest, and $|T_M|\leq |M|\leq k$.  So, $T=T_F\cup T_M$ is in $S$.

For the augmentation property, let $F_1\cup M_1,F_2\cup M_2\in S$ be such that $|F_1\cup M_1|<|F_2\cup M_2|$.  WLOG, assume that $M_1\cap F_1=\emptyset$ and $M_2\cap F_2=\emptyset$.  In the case $|M_2|>|M_1|$, things are pretty easy.  Pick an element $m\in (F_2\cup M_2)\setminus (F_1\cup M_1)$.  We have $$\big|M_1\cup\{m\}\big| =|M_1|+1\leq |M_2|\leq k.$$
So, $(F_1\cup M_1)\cup\{m\}=F_1\cup \big(M_1\cup\{m\}\big)$ is in $S$.  If $|M_2|\leq |M_1|$, then we must have
$$|F_2|-|F_1|\geq \big(|F_2|-|F_1|\big)+\big(|M_2|-|M_1|\big)=\big(|F_2|+|M_2|\big)-\big(|F_1|+|M_1|\big).$$
Because $F_1\cap M_1=F_2\cap M_2=\emptyset$,
$$|F_2|-|F_1|\geq |F_2\cup M_2|-|F_1\cup M_1|>0.$$
Therefore, the forest $F_1$ has more connected components than $F_2$ (recalling that the number of connected components in a forest on $n$ vertices and $m$ edges is $n-m$).  Therefore, there exists a connected component $C$ of $F_2$ with vertices from at least two connected components of $F_1$.  Therefore, there is an edge $e$ of $C$ that connects two distinct connected components of $F_1$.  Note that $F_1\cup\{e\}$ is still a forest.  So, $(F_1\cup M_1)\cup \{e\}=(F_1\cup\{e\})\cup M_1\in S$.

Comment: If the definition for infinite matroids is as given in the link [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.3919), then your proof works fine even when $G$ is an infinite graph, as long as $k$ is a nonnegative integer (not an infinite cardinal).   The only thing you have to deal with is in your last part, where $F_1$ is a non-spanning forest and $F_2$ is a spanning forest.  Since $F_1$ is not spanning, there exists a connected component $C$ of $F_2$ with vertices from at least two connected components of $F_1$.  The rest is the same.

Comment: I don't understand why $M_0$ is needed to show this. "The second part of the task is simply showing that $M_0(G)$ is a matroid, which is implied by the first part."

Comment: I cannot really get my head around your proof for the augmentation property, can you explain your reasoning in more graphical form? 
Thanks for your detailed solution, it helps a lot.

Comment: What does 
$|F2|−|F1|≥(|F2|−|F1|)+(|M2|−|M1|)=(|F2|+|M2|)−(|F1|+|M1|)$ exactly tell us?

Comment: Saying $M_0(G)$ is a matroid is exactly the same as saying that the set of spanning forests form a collection of independent sets of a matroid on the edge set $E$.  And the inequality $$|F_2|-|F_1|\geq \big(|F_2|-|F_1|\big)+\big(|M_2|-|M_1|\big)=\big(|F_2|+|M_2|\big)-\big(|F_1|+|M_1|\big)$$ is there to show that $|F_2|>|F_1|$.